# Call to a member function attach() on boolean - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, foreign-keys, relationship

i have a problem with function attach(). I have created 3 tables. 1 table is for added movies. Table 2 applies to the movie categories. 3 table is a collection of movie ID and category ID. A combination of many to many.

When i want add a new video with category from form this i have error -> Call to a member function attach() on boolean. If anyone knows the answer, please help. Thank you for your time!

VideoController.php -> look at the method store();

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Request;
use App\Http\Requests\CreateVideoRequest;
use App\Video;
use App\Category;
use Auth;
use Session;

class VideoController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct(){
        $this->middleware('auth', ['except' => 'index']);
    }

    public function index(){
        $videos = Video::latest()->get();
        return view('videos.index')->with('videos', $videos);
    }

    public function show($id){
        $video = Video::find($id);  
        return view('videos.show')->with('video', $video);
    }

    public function create(){
        $categories = Category::pluck('name', 'id');
        return view('videos.create')->with('categories',$categories);
    }

    public function store(CreateVideoRequest $request){
        $video = new Video($request->all());
        //dd($request->all());
        Auth::user()->videos()->save($video);

        $categoryIds = $request->input('CategoryList');
        $video->categories()->attach($categoryIds);

        Session::flash('video_created', 'Added');

        return redirect('video');
    }

    public function edit($id){
        $video = Video::findOrFail($id);
        return view('videos.edit')->with('video', $video);
    }

    public function update($id, CreateVideoRequest $request){
        $video = Video::findOrFail($id);
        $video->update($request->all());
        return redirect('video');
    }
}
```

Video.php - model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Video extends Model
{   

    protected $fillable = [
        'title',
        'url',
        'description'
    ];

    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    public function categories(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Video')->withTimestamps;
    }
}
```

Category.php - model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Category extends Model
{

    protected $fillable = [ 'name' ];

    public function videos(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App/Video')->withTimestamps;
    }
}
```

User.php - model (maybe you need a User.php model solves problems)

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    public function videos(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Video');
    }
}
```

Migration - create_category_video_table.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateCategoryVideoTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('category_video', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('category_id');

            $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('video_id');

            $table->foreign('video_id')->references('id')->on('videos')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('category_video');
    }
}
```

Migration - create_categories_table.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateCategoriesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('categories');
    }
}
```

Migration - create_videos_table.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateVideosTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('videos', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');     
            $table->string('title');
            $table->string('url');
            $table->text('description');
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('videos');
    }
}
```

form.blade.php - simple form in Laravel Collection

```
{!! Form::select('CategoryList', $categories, null, ['multiple' => 'multiple']) !!}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the timestamps for the pivot you would call the "method" `withTimestamps()` not a "property" named `withTimestamps`:

```
// Video
public function categories()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class)->withTimestamps();
}

// Category
public function videos()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Video::class)->withTimestamps();
}
```